# How to get (and connect to) IP address of virtualbox A from virtualbox B?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have two virtualboxes A and B.
Both are reachable from host at `192.168.99.101` and `92.168.99.102`.
Also from each of them I can reach host machine at `10.0.2.2`.

How I can get IP of virtualbox A that I could use inside of virtualbox B to connect to virtualbox A?

Comment: The VM should be able to connect with the IP addresses you mentioned. Can you describe what is not working?

Comment: They are on different subnets, so unless the host machine does IP routing, they won't be able to talk to each other.  What is the host machine?

Comment: Host machine is Mac OS X.

Comment: I hope you mean `192.168.99.102`. Do you?

Comment: You should clarify your network design. Host has how many interfaces? With which IPs?